# Python logger not output to file

Tags: python, logging, output, ini

There is something wrong probably with my logging.ini file. My python code works for another file, but not this one.

Python run this `main.py`

```
# main.py
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig

import my_module

# load the logging configuration
fileConfig('logging.ini')

my_module.foo()
bar = my_module.Bar()
bar.bar()
```

Another file with customized methods

```
# my_module.py
import logging

def foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Hi, foo')

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, logger=None):
        self.logger = logger or logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def bar(self):
        self.logger.info('Hi, bar')
        self.logger.debug('Testing')
```

I tried this `logging.ini` file, and it works properly

```
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

Then I would like to save some logs to file, and print some to console, so here I tried another `logging.ini` file

```
[loggers]
keys=root,sLogger

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[formatters]
keys=consoleFormatter,fileFormatter


[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_sLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=sLogger
propagate=0


[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=WARNING
formatter=consoleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_fileHandler]
class=FileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fileFormatter
args=('display_info.log','w')


[formatter_consoleFormatter]
format=%(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=

[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=
```

It was executed like this

```
python main.py
```

This time the program runs fine, no errors. But there is no log in `display_info.log`. Can someone help me on this problem? Thanks!

Comment: So the file is called display_info, but the level is DEBUG.  What is you intent for the file?

Comment: @FrankMerrow I'm guessing OP ran into an issue sending info level messages and is debugging with the debug level

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying to get the logger through `__name__`, which is not `"__main__"`, but is "my_module". You don't have a key for it, so that logger is not configured. Change your `getLogger` to call the proper qualname, `sLogger`, and it grabs the right one:

```py
import logging

def foo():
    # here
    logger = logging.getLogger("sLogger")
    logger.info('Hi, foo')

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, logger=None):
        # or here
        self.logger = logger or logging.getLogger("sLogger")

    def bar(self):
        self.logger.info('Hi, bar')
        self.logger.debug('Testing')
```

This calls the logger by the name you gave it (the `key` it points to in the .ini file). And now your `display_info.log` file should look like:

```
# display_info.log

2020-03-07 22:14:45,351 - sLogger - INFO - Hi, foo
2020-03-07 22:14:45,351 - sLogger - INFO - Hi, bar
2020-03-07 22:14:45,351 - sLogger - DEBUG - Testing
```

The reason is each logger is given a name, so when you call `logging.getLogger(<some_name>)`, that logger is literally called the name you gave it. Then, when you call that logger from other modules, it's already available.

The `__name__` attribute is not the name of the logger, but the name of the script you are running. When you call `python somescript.py`, `somescript.__name__` is `__main__`, because it is the main module being called. But by importing, `__name__` is the name of the module because it's not being executed. So, in effect, what was happening was this:

```py
import logging

''' these two are created when you load the .ini file '''
# this is aliased as root
main_logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")
~ some logging configuration ~

# the other logger you configured
sLogger = logging.getLogger("sLogger")
~ some logging configuration ~
''' and are in global scope in the main script '''

# and the logger you were getting by mistake
logger = logging.getLogger("my_module")


# when you really meant to do this
# which is the same thing as sLogger
logger = logging.getLogger("sLogger")
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep the `__name__` syntax and have module-specific loggers, then you simply add the names of the modules as qualnames:

```
# logging.ini
~ snip ~

[logger_sLogger]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler,fileHandler
qualname=my_module
propagate=0

~ rest of file ~
```

And you can keep the `logging.getLogger(__name__)` call:

```py
# my_module.py
import logging

def foo():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Hi, foo')

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self, logger=None):
        self.logger = logger or logging.getLogger(__name__)

    def bar(self):
        self.logger.info('Hi, bar')
        self.logger.debug('Testing')
```

Comment: @WFL np! I've added a bit more info if you want to keep track via your original `__name__` syntax

Comment: Thanks! So does it mean if I have several other .py files, then I need to add all of their names into my `.ini` file?

Comment: @WFL if you want to keep the `__name__` syntax, then yes